# Load AngularJs Controllers dynamically with ui router and requireJs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

there is some articles and projects that load angularjs controllers dynamically around internet, but I need loading controllers and templates with ui router and requireJs.
how Can I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest googling on the search terms.  When I did this, I was able to find many.

Comment: but I couldn't find a mix of these two tools (requirejs and ui-router).

Comment: Try googling "requirejs ui-router angular"

Answer (score -1):

Kolban is right. there is a project named ["ui-router-extras"](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) that can do these kind of things.